# Errors with Python and Fabric 1.x, when parallel processing

Tags: python, fabric

I'm trying to run some scripts on multiple servers simultaneously. I am using Fabric 1.11.1 to run the scripts a list of servers.
Here is the sample code.

```
server1 = ""
server2 = ""

env.parallel = True

@task
@hosts(server1)
@parallel
def run_shell1():
    run("sh shell1.sh")

@task
@hosts(server2)
@parallel
def run_shell2():
    run("sh shell2.sh")
```

And I ran the fab commands like this:

```
fab run_shell1 run_shell2
```

But when I ran the code, I got the error like this:

```
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function inner at 0x0000000003280438>: it's
not found as fabric.tasks.inner
```

There were also some other error messages about multiprocessing/process.py and fabric/job_queue.py, etc.

Comment: Is this your full code? I'm not a fabric expert, but something seems to be missing.

Comment: Yes,it is almost full code. What is missing?

Comment: Not sure, based on the error message I would have expected to see some inner function, like a nested task or something - but maybe it has something to do with `@parallel`, I haven't used that feature myself.

Comment: My bad, it does in fact have something to do with `@parallel` on Windows. See nir0s' answer

Answer (score 2):

There was a known limitation in Fabric 1.x related to this problem:

https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/489

More particularly, see this for the explanation: https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/489#issuecomment-4232091

The gist is that the forking.Popen() implementation for Win32 is causing problems here when multiprocessing.

This is one of the things which was improved through redesign with Fabric 2.x. Now the **Group** class lets you execution the same code on multiple servers. See the [*Getting started* page, section **Multiple Servers**](https://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.6/getting-started.html#multiple-servers).

Comment: Wow, 2 seconds diff :) I will just remove my answer. Nice one!